# EF, Update doesnt work, it says Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to create a layered MVC project but I am having an UPDATE problem in EF. I am getting the following error.

```
Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.
```

I have DAL and BusinessLayer. In DAL, I have the following code for UPDATE

```
public void Update(params T[] entities)
{
    using (var context = new BorselDBEntities())
    {
        foreach (T entity in entities)
        {
            context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }   
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

and this is how I call the DAL from BusinessLayer

```
public void UpdateProduct(params Product[] products)
{
   _productRepository.Update(products);
}
```

Why am I getting the error above and what could I do to fix it?

Comment: can you place a breakpoint and check the entity has id ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One common reason is that context.Entry(entity) fails to get the entity which you want to update.

When you're debugging, see if context.Entry(entity) returns the entity; easily done by putting it on a separate line and setting a breakpoint afer:

```
public void Update(params T[] entities)
{
    using (var context = new BorselDBEntities())
    {
        foreach (T entity in entities)
        {
            var myEntity = context.Entry(entity);
            myEntity.State = EntityState.Modified;
        }   
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

If it's not, you'll need to work back through your code and work out why it's not able to pick it up. Often this will be because the identity/primary key column is not set on 'entity'.

E.g. in an MVC application, if you have an Edit/update form, remember to have a

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
```

Comment: thanks for helping. I tried as you said and context.Entry(entity) return the object as expected. What else should I be checking?

Comment: So "Often this will be because the identity/primary key column is not set on 'entity'." fixed my issue. Added below migration using 'Add-Migration name' 

        public override void Up()
        {
            AlterColumn("dbo.TableName", "Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
            AddPrimaryKey("dbo.Name", "Id");
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropPrimaryKey("dbo.TableName");
        }

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to call the **Attach** method on the **DbSet** for the entity you are updating before you can change it's State.  The local DbContext needs to contain the Entity or it will not know what changes to track.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696261(v=vs.103).aspx